# Shopify: Incorporate Metafields in Javascript

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've got a Javascript set up to display different text based upon which variant is clicked. It works using standard text like this simplified example:

```
$(function() {
  var copyFlavor = [
    '<p>' + 'Some copy goes here' + ' </p><p>' + 'Even more copy goes here' +  '<p>'
  ];
  $("#swatch-0").click(function () {
     $(".product-shop-description").html(copyFlavor[0]);
     console.log(copyFlavor[0]);
  });
```

However, this is difficult for the client to update themselves. So I'm trying to incorporate metafields, so its much easier for the client to add copy.

However, I can't seem to incorporate Liquid into the script. I've tried both this:

```
$(function() {
  var copyFlavor = [
    '{{ product.metafields.flavor0.short_description.value }}'
  ];
  $("#swatch-0").click(function () {
     $(".product-shop-description").html(copyFlavor[0]);
     console.log(copyFlavor[0]);
  });
```

or....

$(function() {
$("#swatch-0").click(function () {
$(".product-shop-description").html('{{ product.metafields.flavor0.short_description.value }}');
console.log('{{ product.metafields.flavor0.short_description.value }}');
});

Neither of which work and the function breaks.

Any idea of a way to incorporate metafields into this script?

Comment: Is this script being used in a file that is in the `assets` folder or one of the other folders in the theme? The answer will be a bit different depending on that bit of context. :)

Comment: This answer I wrote a few years ago doesn't directly answer your question, but may have parts of what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228583/access-metafields-in-the-product-object-custom-fields-from-accentuate-custom-fi/52391040#52391040